# Download textarea contents as a file using only Javascript (no server-side)

Tags: javascript, html, download, content-disposition

I am being asked to make a "download" button that downloads the contents of a textarea on the same page as a file, with the browser's "Save As..." dialog showing up. Copy/paste would do the job just fine, but it is a "requirement".

Right now, I am just posting the contents of the textarea to the server, which echos them back with `Content-disposition: attachment` slapped on. Is there a way to do this with just client-side Javascript?

Answer (score 31):

This may be what you are looking for:
http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

It uses the browser's download dialogue, but supports only FF and Chrome, and maybe more browsers now?

---

```js
   function saveTextAsFile(textToWrite, fileNameToSaveAs)
    {
     var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'}); 
     var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
     downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
     downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
     if (window.webkitURL != null)
     {
      // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
      // without actually adding it to the DOM.
      downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
     }
     else
     {
      // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
      // before it can be clicked.
      downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
      downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
      downloadLink.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
     }
    
     downloadLink.click();
    }
```

```html
<textarea id=t>Hey</textarea><br>
<button onclick=saveTextAsFile(t.value,'download.txt')>Download</button>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Today it is not neccessary anymore to check for webkitURL. http://caniuse.com/#search=URL
Seems also that Edge still doesnot support this feature

Comment: "Error: destroyClickedElement is not defined" . copying code from the internet is not good for health.

Answer (score 10):

I found a simple solution here: [https://codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/KKaaovd)

```
My text area:<br />
<textarea rows='10' cols='80' id='myTextArea' ></textarea>

<br /><br />

Download button: <br />
<input value='download' type='button'
onclick='doDL(document.getElementById("myTextArea").value)' />


<script type='text/javascript'>
function doDL(s){
    function dataUrl(data) {return "data:x-application/text," + escape(data);}
    window.open(dataUrl(s));
}
</script>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: you are using an invalid content type; doesn't application/octet-stream have the same effect?

Comment: @CyrLop -- awesome answer you posted here.... do you know if theres a way to hardcode a file name so the save dialoge opens with a filename the user can edit, but that is for instance, the current date --  yyyymmdd.txt ?

Comment: @tamak, see my answer below based on this one.

Answer (score 9):

You could try `window.location = "data:application/octet-stream,"+text` but that doesn't provide a mechanism through which you can suggest a name, and also IE has a very small cap on the maximum length of a data URI which could be a problem.

Comment: And it's not even possible with IE6.

Answer (score 7):

There were some javascript libraries that did this kind of thing, via small embedded SWF file. For example [this one](http://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Comment: This is more of an answer to the question in my opinion. I mean, it helped me and thanks for that :)

Comment: Are there other libraries like this one?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `data:` URIs *and* give it a file name, while still downloading the text.  Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("download").onclick = function(){
  var l = document.createElement("a");
  l.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + document.getElementById("dload-txt").value;
  l.setAttribute("download", document.getElementById("dload-fn").value);
  l.click();
}
```

```css
textarea { width: 200px; height: 75px }
input { width: 200px }
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter text to download" id="dload-txt"></textarea><br/>
<input placeholder="Enter file name to download as" id="dload-fn"/><br/><br/>
<button id="download">Download</button>
```

This works in most browsers.

What it does is get the necessary data from the textarea and input, create a link that has an `href` to `data:text/plain;UTF-8,<textarea data>`, and set the `download` attribute with the name set by the `<input>` element.  Then click the link, which will download the text.

The only not-all-browser-compatible things here are:

1. `data:` URIs for storing the data as a link.  [data: URIs on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/datauri)
2. `click()` function to click the link. [HTMLElement.click() on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_click)
3. `download` attribute to signify a download. [download attribute on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/download)

So basically:

- Does not work in IE
- Does not work in Opera Mini
- Does not work in very early versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and iOS Safari

Otherwise, this works in all major browsers, and doesn't need any `Blob` object.

[Blob construction on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/blobbuilder)

[Blob URLs on CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/bloburls)

Comment: don't forget if you want to use special character like \n you have to encode the text

l.href = "data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(content);

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely possible using this cross browser JavaScript implementation of the HTML5 `saveAs` function: https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js

If all you want to do is save text then the above script works in all browsers(including all versions of IE), no SWF required.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Cyrlop's answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41948732/3096687, this gives a way to specify a filename:

```
            function doDownload(str) {
              function dataUrl(data) {
                return "data:x-application/xml;charset=utf-8," + escape(data);
              }
              var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
              downloadLink.href = dataUrl(str);
              downloadLink.download = "foo.xml";

              document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
              downloadLink.click();
              document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            }
```

@Superphonic's solution is likely nicer if you don't mind including more bytes in your JavaScript.

Comment: Know of any way to get it to prompt the user for a save as?

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be possible by creating a frame, writing contents there, then calling
`document.execCommand('saveas', ...)` in IE and something with nsIFilePicker in Mozilla, but I believe that would require some extraordinary privileges (like being part of the browser itself).

Comment: Possible indeed and requires no special privilege.. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/YhdSC/1/ (IE only though :/)

Comment: Yes, the privilege part was more about Firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: it's not posible. 
You have to POST it to server, and response from server can be "Content-disposition: attachment".

Comment: This answer is objectively wrong given I've personally tested and gotten one of these answers working.

Comment: Not sure how this ended up in the VLQ queue - it *is* an answer (just a possibly wrong one). [Wrong answers are not very low quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)