# Bring up Save As dialog within PHP

Tags: php

I have a file, **index2.php** that has been written to by a form.

The whole content of this file, I have stored within a variable `$final_code` using an output buffer.

I now wish to add a "Download" button to the end of the page, that brings up a Save As dialog, allowing the user to save this file's source code (i.e. the variable) as a .txt - But I'm stumped.

**index2.php:**

```
<?php

// Start buffering the output
ob_start();

?>

<!-- INDEX2.PHP HTML ELEMENTS HERE -->

<?php
// Store the contents of the buffer
$final_code = ob_get_contents();

// Print the contents of the buffer
ob_end_flush();
?>

<form action="savefile.php" method="post">

Happy? Save this to file: <input type="submit" name="savefile" value="Save" />

</form>
```

I'm not sure if this needs to be worked in to this file or **savefile.php**, so the latter is currently blank.

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458119/display-save-as-dialog-and-save-contents-of-a-selected-text-inside-textarea-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you cannot force a save as file dialog in browser.

for forceing the download of a txt file i do the following:

```
header('Pragma: anytextexeptno-cache', true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"example.txt\"");
echo $output;
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use headers to force download:

```
 $file = 'somefile.zip';

 if(!file)
 {
     // File doesn't exist, output error
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
     // Set headers
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
     header("Content-Type: application/zip");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

     // Read the file from disk
     readfile($file);
 }
```

Example taken from:
http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download

See link for further explanation.

Comment: How does one get the contents of my variable `$final_code` within this file? Thank you.

Comment: This gives me an "The Compressed (zipped) Folder is invalid or corrupted." error - and it also runs on **index2.php** page load, not on button click...

Comment: Should I move all of this code to **savefile.php** via a hidden form input, and post the $final_code variable there before working on it?

Comment: If it is a text file you are trying to save you will need to change the filename ($file) and content-type to match this. Content-type should be `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for PHP Download Script(from browser) ?