# PHPExcel template load and saving with header

Tags: templates, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to describe a template from Excel with php and then output it.

Problem is that I want to save the file on the desktop but I don't know how to define the path to the desktop?

I would also like to integrate "header" into the file so that the save dialog appears. 
But this doesn't work if I load a template because I get the error message: "File type doesn't fit".

Here is my existing code:

```
// Start
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

// Include Class
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Template loading
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('Template.xlsx');

// Define Values
$test = 'Test';

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B5', $test)                 
            ;


// Excel Document save 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('C:\Users\ ???  \Desktop\Data.xlsx');
```

Thanks for help

Comment: what version of `PHPExcel` ?

Comment: It's version V1.8

Answer (score 0):

you missed a couple of things, you need to specify the `fileType` and an object `createReader` to passe to the `load`

```
// Start
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

// Include Class
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Template loading
$fileType = 'Excel2007'; // use 'Excel5' for .xls files
$fileName = 'Template.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Define Values
$test = 'Test';

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B5', $test)                 
            ;


// Excel Document save with header
$xlsName = 'Document';          
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); // use the header below instead ( for xlsx files )
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); 

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$xlsName.''); // quotes are removed here
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

check this for the save dialog : [bring up save as dialog within php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839142/bring-up-save-as-dialog-within-php)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But how can I integrate the header so that the save dialog appears?

Comment: you can leave you code as it is , just replace this line `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('Template.xlsx');` with the code above,

Comment: See the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have replaced the code. But with the header it doesn't work because I get the message of incompatible file type. The acutual Code is :

```
// Start
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

// Include Class
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Template loading
$fileType = 'Excel2007'; // use 'Excel5' for .xls files
$fileName = 'Template.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

// Define Values
$test = 'Test';

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B5', $test)                 
            ;


// Excel Document save with header
$xlsName = 'Document';          
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xlsName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Where are you having the error? In php? What line? Try with a `xls` file

Comment: I also tried it with an xls file, same problem. I get the message when opening the Excel file that the file extension and the file format do not match.

Comment: i edited my answer to remove the queotes in `Content-Disposition` and changing the `Content-Type`

Comment: Thanks @Taki, but I still get the same error message :( –