# Processing files locally with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, download, local

Using JavaScript I want to:

1. generate a file locally and serve it to the user as
    `Content-Disposition: attachment;`
2. load a file locally from the user via a form `<input type="file" />`

Is this possible, and if so, what is the most straightforward way to do it?

Comment: Is it the same file? Then upload it directly.

Comment: For the first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609530/download-textarea-contents-as-a-file-using-only-javascript-no-server-side

Comment: The way I would do it would be to generate the file with a server-side language (such as PHP), hand it to the user as a download, and then, as you stated, get the file back via file-upload (and then process it in the server).

Comment: For the second question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

Comment: @JCOC611: I know it seems easier and more straightforward that way, but the back-and-forth is precisely what I wanted to avoid when I just want to work with the contents of the file locally.

Comment: @Thilo: thanks for the suggestions, that ought to give me good start.

Comment: @JL344: The reason I suggested that way was because, as far as I know, it's usually easier to work server-side based. However, if you want to work exclusively client-side, then that is much better for the end user. Good luck!

Comment: @Thilo That question and its answers are horribly outdated.