# Javascript download contents of a element

Tags: javascript, html, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download textarea contents as a file using only Javascript (no server-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609530/download-textarea-contents-as-a-file-using-only-javascript-no-server-side)

Basically I have a live html editor in javascript and I want to add the ability for the user to click a  button or link and download their html document.  My idea was just to download the file with the contents of the textarea element, but I can't seem to find out how.
I do have php if any server-side things are needed, it doesn't have to be strictly javascript but I want an option to do this.  Thanks!  And please comment because sometimes my questions can be rather confusing :|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609530/download-textarea-contents-as-a-file-using-only-javascript-no-server-side

Comment: So send a request to the server and just send it back?

Comment: I say that's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Alright thanks for the link and info!

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an another simple way to do this on the client side itself, i believe that will be a best fit for you because, the html editing is done on the client side and you dont need any server data.

http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html

the above component lets us download a content from the client side and WYSIWYG editor is a DIV with a Contenteditable true attribute which allows editing, so you can get the html content and pass it on to this component for client side download